# No publishable resources for tag [jetstream-views]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

When I run "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views" the results "INFO No publishable resources for tag [jetstream-views]", is there any other ways to do this? Is there any other syntax that is similar?

When I run "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views", it should appear like this:
INFO Publishing [jetstream-views] assets.
Copying directory [vendor/laravel/jetstream/resources/views] to [resources/views/vendor/jetstream] DONE

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, in the latest version, there's no need to use `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views` anymore because when you install Jetstream, the required views will be copied to the `resources/js/Pages/` directory (https://jetstream.laravel.com/concept-overview.html).

If, for example, you need to modify the login page, simply make your changes in `resources/js/Pages/Auth/Login.vue` and then run the `npm run build` command.

If you need the `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views` command for other purposes, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Re-install Jestream using: composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install